# StoryBook and Angular Configuration

Tags: angular, webpack, storybook

I'm trying to config environment for my storybook with hybrid project Angular 7 & AngularJS.
I need to work with shared components in this storybook from Angular 7 but because I have hybrid project in my angular.json config I have build assets which related to files from AngularJS and when I run my storybook it also take it

```html
 "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
            ...
            "assets": [
               {"input": "src/legacy", "glob": "**/*", "output": "legacy"},
               {"input": "src/assets", "glob": "**/*", "output": "assets"},
               {"input": "src/content", "glob": "**/*", "output": "content"},
               ]
           ...
          }
```

How it possible to change connect and send command to storybook to run it with configuration without files which related to another projects.
Thanks